# How to send back a fake response(header and body) from an intercepted request via mitmproxy

Tags: python, http, httprequest, httpresponse, mitmproxy

I need a way using python3 and mitmproxy and any other python3 libraries (if posssible) to fake(simulate) a full response(header and body) by intercepting the filtered request and reply back with a fake response without even sending the real request to the server.

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use mitmproxy's [server replay feature](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/overview-features/#server-side-replay), or script it yourself manually: [examples/addons/http-reply-from-proxy.py](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/master/examples/addons/http-reply-from-proxy.py).

Comment: I didn't knew that mitmproxy supports that already.